# i am trying to change the border-bottom to 'none' on click in <li> menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small menu with 3 items and basically when I click one of the li's I wish to be able to change the border-bottom to none, here are my codes, html javascript and css

http://jsfiddle.net/6csm2/1/

this is the problem i suspect, either that or the css is laid out wrong..

> ```
> $(this).css('background-color' , '#ffffff');
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem actually lies somewhere else, you are able to change the bottom border to none, however you have defined border line for all of the menu and also for the itmes so even though you change the border to none on click, there will still be your menu border.

to solve this remove border from profile_menu and change the mentioned line to:

```
$(this).css('background-color','#ffffff');
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6csm2/9/

Answer (score 1):

this is the right way to do it..  here is [sample working](http://jsfiddle.net/6csm2/5/)

```
$(this).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
```

they both go in the same... also why do it with jquery if css is way faster since is just a color change.

Answer (score 1):

i think you meant to do this:

```
$(this).css('background-color','#ffffff');
```

Answer (score 1):

*same answer as others* , but for the **bottom border you better choose a color** than none :
http://jsfiddle.net/6csm2/7/

```
$(function() {
$('.profile_menu_buttons').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color' , '#ffffff');
    $(this).css('border-bottom' , '1px solid transparent');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take the brackets out in the middle of your code. Try this...

```
$(this).css('background-color','#ffffff');
```

Answer (score 0):

A everyone has said - you had a typo, it should be:

```
 $(this).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
```

However, most people seem to have missed the fact he wanted to remove the border at the bottom of the selected tab as well. He needs an .active class, something more like:

http://jsfiddle.net/6csm2/13/

I can't quite get the bottom border to work right though (doesn't hide it fully). Maybe someone else wants a go at that?

Comment: you "can't" hide it, see my answer

Comment: @MatúšDúbrava - You can - just not with the method he is using. I've done it several times on jobs. You just have to use a different approach (floating the element, and overlapping a div below - which has a border).

Comment: well that is the reason why I typed "can't" in quotes

Comment: Sure. Your example also seems to have missed out the fact he wanted to change the background color to white ;)

Comment: There is no such request in the question, only to remove the bottom border and one reference to invalid code ;)

Comment: haha - but in his original code it did this <G> Anyhow, it doesnt matter - just saying that my code does both :)

Comment: yeah i messed up the question, it was background-color white and border-bottom 1px solid white

Comment: seems i was to tired to realise i was doing the wrong code.